# integral of fractional function

Tags: integration, approximation-theory, integral-transforms

Let $a>2$ be a real variable. My objective is to find an approximation of the integral defined as
\begin{equation}
\int_b^{ + \infty } {\frac{x}{{1 + {x^a}}}}. 
\end{equation}
Here $b$ is a positive real number.

Comment: In what regime? $b\to 0$ and $b\to\infty$ are easy, but the answers are different. The intermediate range is when life gets hard. Also, what would you consider a "good approximation"? What precision are you aiming at and what computation time can you afford?

Comment: To the (potential) voters to close: I would wait until the OP has a chance to explain what he or she is really after here.

Comment: Do you mean computing the integral numerically for given $a,b$? Softwares can do this, for example Pari/GP with the function intnum, by specifying the behavior $\sim x^{1-a}$ at $+\infty$.

Comment: For example in the case $a=5/2$ and $b=1$, intnum(x=1, [+oo, -3/2], x/(1+x^(5/2))) gives 1.7766271453035772760815104540407586926.

Comment: Integral does not converge for $a<2$, otherwise it is given by $\frac{b^{2-a} \, _2F_1\left(1,\frac{a-2}{a};2-\frac{2}{a};-b^{-a}\right)}{a-2}$

Comment: @FrançoisBrunault And what is the actual precision of that? It is definitely not 35 digits and most likely better than 3, but how do I figure out what it is? Anyway, this article https://www.math.ucla.edu/~mason/research/pearson_final.pdf describes the ways to compute ${}_2F_1$ with 16 digit precision in 10 seconds or so, but I suspect that the OP's game is exactly the opposite: minimal acceptable precision but really high speed...

Comment: @fedja I'm quite confident the result is correct to 35 digits (it is stable when increasing precision). It takes 5 ms. It would be good to have confirmation but Pari/GP doesn't have hypergeometrics.

Comment: @fedja Sorry, I'm behind, Pari/GP now has the function hypergeom. I used yarchik's expression and it matches the intnum result to 35 digits. The hypergeom computation just takes 2 ms.

Comment: @FrançoisBrunault At least the last 5 digits are bogus: make the change of variable $x=y^2$ and integrate again to compare. That I know for sure. And you were confident in all 35. See what I'm driving at? :-)

Comment: @fedja I made the change of variables and the integral over $y$ gives the same result. Increasing the precision, you find the last 5 digits are 86925 and then 56221...

Comment: @fedja This integral is also $2\sum_{n \geq 0} (-1)^n/(5n+1)$ and Pari/GP's function sumalt gives the same result.

Comment: @ yarchik can you give a development or references for your result?

Comment: @FrançoisBrunault OK, try intnum (x=1,oo, 1/((x-100)^2+1)) then. We both know that you cannot get more than 4 here. The output (completely confident) is 13.30483207523167247713006706. How do I know when to trust and when not to trust after that?

Comment: @fedja Right, I cannot even get something close to 13. The best I know is numerical integration in Arb, which gives you guaranteed precision. https://fredrikj.net/blog/2017/11/new-rigorous-numerical-integration-in-arb/  However here, the interval is infinite and you need to truncate manually, see the paragraph "Infinite intervals and endpoint singularities"

Comment: @fedja With Pari/GP, you can of course check that the result is stable by increasing precision.

Comment: @FrançoisBrunault Sure, but this is a one way road and in the direction that is the least interesting of the two: if the output changes, then I know it is bogus, but not necessarily the other way around. PariGP is a very good software, no question, but I still wouldn't trust "all 35 digits" it outputs. That's not only a practical problem, IMHO, but also a philosophical one: we somehow developed an over-reliance on the computers that comes not from our good knowledge of their capabilities and the underlying algorithms but rather from the lack thereof. Don't you agree? :-) I'll try Arb too.

Comment: @fedja That's a good point, believing blindly a computer is a trap that many people can fall into. To be sure/confident in the output requires a good understanding of both the problem and how the computer actually works internally. I like Arb since uncertainty is potentially eliminated, but the point still applies. In our case, getting the same value with 4 different methods and after increasing precision is enough for me to trust the output. The integration method is very robust for analytic functions on a finite interval but I admit I don't completely know what happens with infinite endpoint

Comment: @FrançoisBrunault *To be sure/confident in the output requires a good understanding of both the problem and how the computer actually works internally.* That's exactly the point I was driving at. I'm happy that you stated it yourself and you couldn't state it better :-) That's why I find the advice of the type "softwares can do it" to a person (if that is a person; the other posts and reactions fail the Turing test so far IMO, but it is none of my business) who rather clearly doesn't understand either part well somewhat flawed. Do you agree here? :-)

Comment: @fedja I agree in general, but in cases where the output is highly trustworthy (at least from our experience, which cannot be considered as proof) the advice is still good, I think. Ideally we should always additionally explain what the computer does and warn about what could go wrong, for sure.

Comment: @FrançoisBrunault *in cases where the output is highly trustworthy* That's why I always ask about the parameter range and precision before deciding whether something I can offer is "highly trustworthy". But yes, I agree that the advice is not generally necessarily "bad", just "somewhat flawed", as I said. BTW, I suspect that infinite limits in intnum are handled by the Richardson extrapolation or something similar. At least, that would explain both the amazing precision in some cases and the bizarre behavior in others.

Comment: @fedja I would say this is similar to mathematicians not explaining what is self-evident for them. They do this all the time :) The function intnum in Pari/GP uses the double exponential method, you can have details here: https://arxiv.org/abs/1809.10904 see Section 8.7. He also explains the bad behaviour for the integral you mentioned, that's because of the poles of $1/(1+x^2)$ are too close to the integration domain, in a relative sense. In our case we were integrating with $b>0$ which made me confident, although further checks are always welcome.

Comment: @FrançoisBrunault *mathematicians not explaining what is self-evident for them. They do this all the time* Actually, they do it only when talking to people whom they assume to already know the stuff necessary to understand the rest. But that assumption can be wrong and then such explanations end up with blank stares, polite nods and total confusion on the listener side. :-) But I'll agree about the similarity, and IMO that is also not such a great practice.

Answer (score 2):

Write $\int_b^\infty = \int_0^\infty - \int_0^b$. The first integral gives a Beta function, which evaluated yields $\frac{\pi}{a\sin(2\pi/a)}$. If $b^a\ll 1$, you can get a good approximation to the second integral by converting the integral to a weighted geometric series and integrating term by term, obtaining $$b^2\sum_{k=0}^\infty (-1)^k \frac{b^{ak}}{ak+2}.$$ In this mentioned regime, your integral is
$$\frac{\pi}{a\sin(2\pi/a)}+b^2/2-\frac{b^{a+2}}{a+2}+\mathcal{O}(b^{2a+2}).$$